# Accessing character array through pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with accessing characters and when they are converted to ASCII numbers without explicitly doing so. Consider the the code below:

```
include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  char* p;

  char s[100]="hello world";

  p=s;

  cout<<p[2]<<endl;//This gives the actual character from the string "hello 
  //world": "l"

  p=p+p[4]-p[2];//But this does something different, it basically uses

//ASCII values of the characters at p[4] and p[2] and uses them to do 
//pointer arithmetic

   cout<<p;// gives "lo world"

   return 0;

 }
```

Comment: "My question is: Why does the line "cout<" - what?

Comment: Hint: a character is really just a (small) integer.

Comment: Use std::string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't get a compilation error when using `p=p+p[4]-p[2]` despite the expression having `p[4]` and `p[2]`, which should return character values?

In C++ `char` is considered an *integral data type*, so it is treated as an integer type with a small range of values.

C++ defines pointer addition/subtraction operations that take integers on the right side. Since `char` is an integral type, its value is promoted to `int` for the pointer arithmetics operation.

Answer (score 1):

That's because p is holding the base address. The ascii value of 'o' (p[4]) is 111 and the ascii value of 'l' (p[2]) is 108.

when you do p = p + p[4] - p[2]

you are updating the base address. That is let's assume the base address of p is x.

after the updatation p will be x + 111 - 108 => x + 3.

Thus the string that you are getting is "lo world", the first three characters "hel" are getting skipped.

Comment: Do note that ascii is not a requirement and the value of the characters is implementation defined.

Comment: The question is not that why he is getting the show output. The question is that why `char` is implicitly converted to `int` without explicitly doing so. **Note -** I saw that before it was edited. Now OP removed that part.